# What is the canonical document schema for representing UML?

Tags: xsd, uml, rdf, owl

I want to represent UML models in a serialized document using the most standard conventions available.  I am looking for a canonical schema document that explicitly dictates the best way to do this.  I suspect that, if such a document exists, then it would be written in either XSD, RDF and OWL.  So far, I have only been able to find OMG specification documents and academic papers on the subject.  I have found some XSD schemas, but they only apply to a particular aspect of the implementation.

1. Is there a canonical document schema?  Where can I find it?  If not, what are the most common representation formats and where can I find their schemas?
2. Are there any libraries that facilitate the generation of mappings from well-formed documents of this kind to graphical representations (e.g. SVG)?  The library would ideally be .NET compatible, but this is not a requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [XMI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) (XML Metadata Interchange)?  It's an OMG spec for XML representations of UML models; the current version appears to be [2.4.1](http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.4.1/), and the spec page links to two XSD schema documents.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, XMI should answer part of your first question. XMI is not, however, without perils. From my own experience trying to achieve exactly the same, I would think that the first thing to do is to understand what others did about it, and how these standard documents would be used. These days I would suggest a system setup that involves [IBM RSA](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/r/architect/) and [Sparx Enterprise Architect](http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/) (eval versions available, registration may be required, and I am not affiliated with any of these companies). Build at least one comprehensive UML model which would give you the coverage you need, in one tool, then use the XMI export/import function to move the model between them. See what happens. Take a look at a company such as [this](http://www.reischmann.com/) (the makers of TOOLBUS, not affiliated with them) and think how XMI should affect their business model, and yet it seems that it doesn't...

I would think that success is achievable, but may prove feasible for a (very) narrow scope - scoping is key here.

As for the second part, I don't think you're going to find it, particularly for .NET.

Answer (score 0):

XMI is the keyword you need. But XMI specifies only the document format. It does specify the document structure or contents. The UML metamodel does this. A library which does both for you is org.eclipse.uml2 - it implements the UML 2.4 metamodel and allows to store and restore it in XMI. IBM RSA uses this library as well. As several other Java Tools do.

I'm not aware of a UML2 implementation in a .NET language.

Comment: Visual Studio 10+ contain modeling tools that support UML, but I'm not sure if it's free to use or not (I actually have another open question on that)

Comment: As far as I can tell the UML capabilities of VS10 are only in the Ultimate Edition (not free). And beware: It's not UML2.x compliant UML and you can't write standard compliant files from it.